# map.on('click',onClick) is also fired when zoomBox

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have defined a `map.on('click',onClick)` event, but it also fires when someone uses the zoomBox Handler (Shift+draw zoom box)

```
function onClick(e) {alert(e.latlng);}
```

`e.type` is always 'click'

I am using **Leaflet version 0.5.1**.

How can I avoid this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you change it to use mousedown and mouseup - then have them both edit a variable, work out the time between down and up, then if not too long, fire the click function? If that makes sense lol

Comment: I think the problem is that the click is going through the zoomBox Handler. Try adding a click listener to the zoom handler and adding stopPropagation().
With jQuery:
$('#zoombox').on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation()
});

Comment: My answer just above should work, but it's a bit of a hack as this behaviour does not happen on http://leafletjs.com/ after adding the click event through the console. Is it possible that you somehow changed the "map" variable to reference the containing div and not the map element itself? Do you have a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP too much dependencies coming around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found a bug! I found this *bug* appears in IE 10 only, and not only 0.5.1, but 0.6 also has same issue. You can [report a bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-bugs) to [Leaflet issue tracker](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues).

For now, temporary, you can track `mousedown` point and compare to `click` point to determine whether cursor is moved.

```
var mousedownPoint; // global

map.on('mousedown', function (e) {
  mousedownPoint = e.containerPoint;
});

map.on('click', function (e) {
  if (!e.containerPoint.equals(mousedownPoint)) {
    return;
  }

  // DO WHAT YOU WANT
});
```

Comment: this is great! but for using equals function you have to pass a latlng as parameter, so the code (tested) works like below.

This bug appears to me also in most recent version of Firebug and Chrome.

var mousedownPoint; // global

map.on('mousedown', function (e) {
  mousedownPoint = e.latlng;
});

map.on('click', function (e) {
  if (!e.latlng.equals(mousedownPoint)) {
    return;
  }

  // DO WHAT YOU WANT
});